# SQL Azure Database size - internal table plan_persist_plan

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are having an issue with our SQL Azure databases, as they increase size, mainly because of one internal system table - plan_persist_plan.

In one of the databases, with a total size of **400Mb**, the **plan_persist_plan** table represents by itself **310Mb** and the rest are mainly user tables and indexes.

We calculate the database size with the following query:

```
SELECT sum(reserved_page_count)*8.0/1024 FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

To know each object size, we use:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), reserved_page_count*8.0/1024, * FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats order by reserved_page_count desc
```

Can anyone please explain:

1. The purpose of this table - plan_persist_plan?
2. How can we control it's size and possibly shrink it?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this, and searches don't turn up anything. I've done a bunch of experimentation and I suspect it's something to do with Plan Store internals. Every database I've tested this on has had the plan_persist_plan as 0 pages. You might wait a bit and try again. If not, contacting Microsoft directly might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

With experimentation, what I'm seeing is that plan_persist_plan is part of the Query Store internals. With Query Store disabled and cleared, there is no data in this table. Enabling Query Store and I immediately see data added to the table and it grows as the queries I run grow. I then disabled Query Store and the information in plan_persist_plan was still there. I then cleared Query Store and that information went away.

I think you're calculating the size a little wrong though. By default out of the box the max for query store is 100mb. Unless you've changed that I don't see how it's storing 300mb.

If you want to try this, run:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET QUERY_STORE CLEAR;
```

Substituting your database name.